# Two characters in a for loop not comparing properly

Tags: php

I narrowed down my problem to `if($reqFnameArr[$i] == $fnameArr[$i])` I don't know why it's not comparing properly those two variables contain single characters from the split. Because when I try to output `$finUsername` is stays empty.

```
//fetch firstname in Database
$fname = User::select('first_name')->where('username', $request->username)
                  ->where('first_name', '!=', $request->first_name)->get();
$fnameArr = str_split($fname);
//request firstname
$reqFname = $request->first_name;
$reqFnameArr = str_split($reqFname);
//final username
$finUsername = '';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($reqFname); $i++) {
  if($reqFnameArr[$i] == $fnameArr[$i]) {
  $finUsername .= $reqFnameArr[$i];
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I am saving finUsername to a database after comparing the arrays

```
  $user = User::create($request->all());

              $user->update(['role_id' => $request->role]);
              $user->save();
              $user->update(['username' => $finUsername]);
              $user->save();

              $roleName = $user->role()->name;

              return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'roleName' => $roleName,'manager_exists'=>'0']);
```

Comment: Please also provide the specific data you apparently get from some database so that we can test your statement. Thanks.

Comment: It's just two strings that are split into arrays 'Hello1' for $fname and 'Hello2' for $reqFname for example. I'll provide a screen shot of the db in a sec. $reqFname is from a form btw.

Comment: Better if you specify what is your goal to do this. What do you want with example.

Comment: I edited my post to see the db save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do here. Why the php string comparing functions are not used. But to answer your question:

That code of yours does output the common part of two strings sure enough. Take a look at this simple demonstration:

```
<?php

$fname = 'Hello1';
$fnameArr = str_split($fname);

$reqFname = 'Hello2';
$reqFnameArr = str_split($reqFname);

//final username
$finUsername = '';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($reqFname); $i++) {
    if($reqFnameArr[$i] == $fnameArr[$i]) {
        $finUsername .= $reqFnameArr[$i];
    }
}
var_dump($finUsername);
```

The output is:

> string(5) "Hello"

So most likely your *real* issue is that your attempt to fetch those two names does *not* deliver the values you claim, but most likely at least one empty string or something that evaluates to that when converted.

Comment: You are right it turns out my fname returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

Its comparing. I have done some R&D. You can test this way.

> ```
> $fname ='Hello1'; $reqFname ='Hello2';
>
>  $fnameArr = str_split($fname);
>
>           //request firstname //   $reqFname = $request->first_name;
>           $reqFnameArr = str_split($reqFname); //print_r($reqFnameArr); //print_r($fnameArr);
>           //final username
>           $finUsername = '';
>
>           for($i = 0; $i < strlen($reqFname); $i++) {
>             // echo $reqFnameArr[$i].'  '.$fnameArr[$i];die;
>             if($reqFnameArr[$i] == $fnameArr[$i]) {
>               //  echo 'coming here';
>               $finUsername.= $reqFnameArr[$i];
>             }
>           } echo $finUsername;
> ```

Let me know if you have any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use strict comparison operator === instead of == when comparing two string.

```
if($reqFnameArr[$i] === $fnameArr[$i]) {
```

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php